# How to find endpoint coordinates with given start, length, and euler angles

Tags: three.js, trigonometry

I'm working on some 3d fractals...  If I take any arbitrary point (x,y,z), start from there, and then draw a line of given length "d", in a direction defined by Euler angles... (by rotation A about the x-axis, B about the y-axis, and C about the z-axis) -- and then calculate the resulting endpoint of the line.

This would be simple in 2 dimensions, as I could find the endpoint like:

```
endX = beginX + d * cos(angle)
endY = beginY + d * sin(angle)
```

Basically, I need to fill in the blanks here:

```
endX = beginX + d * (??)
endY = beginY + d * (??)
endZ = beginZ + d * (??)
```

Where I only know angles defined by 3 rotations, 1 about each axis

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642687/given-start-point-angles-in-each-rotational-axis-and-a-direction-calculate-end?rq=1