# Given point A, angles and length to point B. Calculate point B

Tags: matlab, math, 3d, trigonometry, angle

Let's assume I have a start point A in 3D coordinates (0, 0, 0). I have 3 Eular angles (yaw, pitch and roll) and distance L from the start point (X cm) to the end point B.

How can I calculate the coordinates of point B?

I believe that the answer might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642687/given-start-point-angles-in-each-rotational-axis-and-a-direction-calculate-end), but since my background is not in math I am a bit struggling to understand it. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you have a problem with math, you might want to ask that in [**math.se**](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: enough information can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/coordinate-systems-in-robotics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link:

If you are using MATLAB, make sure your angles are in radians. If your start point X = [0,0,0], then:

Bx = 0 + L * cos (Yaw Angle) * sin (Pitch Angle)

By = 0 + L * sin (Yaw Angle)

Bz = 0 + L * cos (Yaw Angle) * cos (Pitch Angle)