# Get position by having start position, turn and distance

Tags: math, 3d, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

How to get end point (3d) given start position as 3d point, direction as 3d rotation (0-360 in x, y and z) and distance? Values:

```lua
local x, y, z = 0,0,0 -- starting position
local rx, ry, rz = 0, 180, 360 -- rotation
local distance = 10 -- distance

local destinationX, destinationY, destinationZ = ... -- endpoint
```

I know about https://wiki.multitheftauto.com/wiki/GetPointFromDistanceRotation but that won't help me as all 3 endpoint values are important to me

Yes, I saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642687/given-start-point-angles-in-each-rotational-axis-and-a-direction-calculate-end), but I have Z - the vertical axis (GTA San Andreas), no matter how I tried the first answer on this topic, I could not do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a starting point *P = (x, y, z)*. Then you have a direction vector *v = (1, 0, 0)*, which you rotate using *rx*, *ry*, *rz*.

With *rx*, *ry*, *rz* you can calculate the rotation matrix R using these equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations

Then, the final point would be:

[image: equation]